# Latin Language Stack Exchange graduates!

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Our site, Latin Language Stack Exchange, loses its beta status and graduates to a full site on December 16th, 2021.
Congratulations everyone, and many thanks for your commitment to our site and the community!

What this means in practice:

1. The "beta" label disappears everywhere.
2. We're here to stay.
   We are considered a proper and stable site.
   Think of it as the end of the trial period of a permanent contract.
3. The reputation thresholds for privilege levels will stay where they are.
   There is no need to strip users of privileges; we want consistent contributors to be able to use the site as efficiently as before.
4. There might be some customization to the site's appearance.
   We shouldn't expect anything major or quick, so there will be a separate announcement if any such customization opportunities come our way.
   Don't count on this.
5. Migrations to and from this site will be easier and do not necessarily require a moderator.
   In practice this need is likely to be small enough that it is easiest handled by contacting a moderator, but we now get the ability to set up migration paths — after a due process including an assessment of need and a meta discussion.
6. There will be an election.
   The current *pro tempore* moderators will remain in office until the election, so there will be no discontinuity.
   The whole moderator team will be elected, so none of the current moderators continue automatically.
   Everyone, including current moderators, have to run if they want to be moderators on the graduated site.
   As many sites are graduating at the same time, the many elections will be spread through the year 2022 and some might go into 2023.
   There will be separate announcements when the election is near; this is just a heads-up so that you can consider whether you might want to run.

If you have any questions, comments, concerns, or anything else you'd like to share, comment or answer.
The list above is unlikely to be fully exhaustive.

---

Network-wide announcements:
[The mother of all meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/321340) and [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/).

Comment: Laeta affers. Crescat et floreat etiam novo gradu contacto nostra sodalitas.

Comment: Ω φίλοι, χαίρωμεν!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations everyone!

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thank you for proposing the site back in 2014!