# Latin SE graduation election comes this August

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Latin Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **August 15th**, as your “graduation” election [as a result of having lost your beta label a while back](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/561/6).

The timeline:

- On August 8th, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 15th, users can [nominate themselves](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On August 22nd, if there are 5 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 5 candidates, I'll simply cancel the election and post to Meta to determine next steps. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 30th (or September 6th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.